# up vector for quaternion

Tags: xna, rotation, quaternion

First, I know there's a [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53129/quaternion-look-at-with-up-vector) exactly like mine, and some ohter really close, but my implementation of the solutions didn't work at all. Ok, now to the question.

I created some forms of camera based on quaternions, however, for my *orbit/chase* camera every quaternion I create will roll the camera in an uncontrollable manner. What I want is a function like Unity's [Quaternion.LookRotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) where you can pass an up vector.
This is a simplification current attempt of implementation:

```
Vector3 target = -Position; //Because we're looking at the origin
target.Normalize();

float cosine = Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Forward, target);
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Forward, target);
Rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, (float)Math.Acos(cosine));

//Trying to unroll up vector to Vector3.Up
//based on the other answer but results were unchanged
Vector3 rolledUp = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Up, Rotation);
Vector3 right = Vector3.Cross(target, Vector3.Up);
Vector3 newUp = Vector3.Cross(right, target);

Vector3 axis2 = Vector3.Cross(rolledUp, newUp);
float angle2 = (float) Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(rolledUp,newUp));

Rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis2, angle2) * Rotation;

return Matrix.CreateLookAt(
    cameraPosition: Position,
    cameraTarget: Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Forward, Rotation),
    cameraUpVector: Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Up, Rotation));
```

If my sleepiness got in the way of my clarity, here's what I have:
[image: quaternion result]

and here's what I want:
[image: rotation matrix based result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should only need to rotate around the y axis or you can just say to look at the point on the y-axis at the same height of the camera

```
target.y=0; 
target.normalize();
```

of course then you can start to optimize because `axis` is `(0,1,0)` and all the other ups will be the same again (do double check that though)